# Сохранение значения checkbox

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-shared-preferences

Имеется checkbox в item menu, не получается сохранять его позицию(чекнут или не чекнут).

Пробую сохранять значение таким кодом:

```
case R.id.menuHideShowTime:
            if(item.isChecked()){
                item.setChecked(false);
            }else{
                adapter.toggleStateTime(); //вывод значения
                item.setChecked(true);
            }
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("menuHideShowTime", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("menuHideShowTime",item.isChecked());
            editor.commit();

            break;
```

Но, не получается, при смене активности и переходе в него братно - значение чекбокса не чекнуто

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.message_menu, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menuHideShowTime);
    SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    item.setChecked(settings.getBoolean("menuHideShowTime", false));

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: Вы в onCreate достаёте сохранённое значение и устанавливаете его на CheckBox? Покажите, как вы это делаете.

Comment: в onCreateOptionsMenu

Comment: Почему вы не указываете имя файла, когда достаёте значение? SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("menuHideShowTime", MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: Вместо editor.commit(); предпочтительнее использовать editor.apply(); http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960678/whats-the-difference-between-commit-and-apply-in-shared-preference

Comment: Не помогает, значение все равно не сохраняется

Comment: Почему вы устанавливаете значение MenuItem item? Нужно ведь устанавливать на CheckBox.

Comment: checkbox ведь находится в menuitem

Comment: Да, вы правы... Однако, если вы подправили всё на getSharedPreferences("menuHideShowTime", 0);, не знаю, где может быть ошибка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Установите его значение в `onCreateOptionsMenu`;

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("settings", 0);
    boolean isChecked = settings.getBoolean("checkbox", false);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_check);
    item.setChecked(isChecked);
    return true;
```

}

А в `onOprionsItemSelected` сохраняйте выбранное значение;

```
if (id == R.id.action_check) {
    item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("settings", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("checkbox", item.isChecked());
    editor.apply();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Когда вы пишите

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("menuHideShowTime", 0);
```

Создаётся файл с именем "menuHideShowTime". Этот метод используется, когда нужно использовать несколько разных файлов для сохранения данных.

Когда пишите так:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Данные записываются в один общий файл.

Вам нужно писать одинаково для одних и тех же данных. Иначе не получиться их найти.

Кстати, значение MODE_PRIVATE равно 0. Можно указывать и то, и то.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что сохраняете вы значение в `SharedPreferences`, а пытаетесь выгрузить из `Prefereces`. Это **не одно и то же**. `Preferences` сохраняют данные в специально отведенный для этого файл, `SharedPreferences` же используют тот файл, который укажете вы. Для решения проблемы нужно выбрать один из объектов и использовать только его.